# left outer join in linq error at defaultifempty

Tags: c#, linq

so i have 3 tables 
i want to do left outer join on all 3 but say

table 1 has

```
id   name
1    peter
2    john
```

table 2 has

```
id address
1   123 ave 
2   456 blvd
```

table 3 has

```
table1id table2id
1           1
1           2
2           1 
2           2
```

table 3 is a xref of table 1 and 2

so if i add one record into table 1, when i search by name, i need to get name and address that name associates with, but it returns nothing because i haven't inserted anything into table 3 yet. so i'm trying to do a left join but i run into an error

```
var query = from t1 in table1 
            join t3 in table3 on t1.id equals t3.table1id into leftt1 
            from l1 in leftt1.defaultifempty() 
            join t2 in table2 on l1.table2id equals t2.id 
            select.......
```

the error is at defaultifempty. it actually returns empty instead of the new record i just added. is there something wrong with my left outer join? please help. thanks

Comment: I'd suggest to change table2 definition to: `Id, Table1Id, Address`. Third table is unnecessary ;(

Comment: C# is case sensitive, so `defaultifempty` is not the same as `DefaultIfEmpty`...

Comment: no i put it there to describe i was too lazy to use type it correctly. like i said, the code syntax is fine just that instead of returning left table record, it returns as inner join instead of left join. and  since its a many to many i need third table for references. for 3rd normal form.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for clarification.

Assuming the description of issue, i think you need to use `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`, because 3rd table stores data which exist in 1st and 2nd table.

See example (using LinqPad):

```
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("id", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
dt1.Columns.Add(dc);
dc = new DataColumn("name", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
dt1.Columns.Add(dc);
dt1.Rows.Add(new Object[]{1, "Peter"});
dt1.Rows.Add(new Object[]{2, "John"});


DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
dc = new DataColumn("id", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
dt2.Columns.Add(dc);
dc = new DataColumn("address", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
dt2.Columns.Add(dc);
dt2.Rows.Add(new Object[]{1, "123 ave"});
dt2.Rows.Add(new Object[]{2, "456 blvd"});

DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();
dc = new DataColumn("id1", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
dt3.Columns.Add(dc);
dc = new DataColumn("id2", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
dt3.Columns.Add(dc);
dt3.Rows.Add(new Object[]{1, 1});
dt3.Rows.Add(new Object[]{1, 2});
dt3.Rows.Add(new Object[]{2, 1});
dt3.Rows.Add(new Object[]{2, 2});

var qry = from refdata in dt3.AsEnumerable()
        join userdata in dt1.AsEnumerable() on refdata.Field<int>("id1") equals userdata.Field<int>("id")
        join addressdata in dt2.AsEnumerable() on refdata.Field<int>("id2") equals addressdata.Field<int>("id")
        select new
        {
            uid = userdata.Field<int>("id"),
            uname = userdata.Field<string>("name"),
            aid = addressdata.Field<int>("id"),
            aadress = addressdata.Field<string>("address")
        };
```

Result:

```
uid    uname    aid   aadress
1      Peter    1     123 ave 
1      Peter    2     456 blvd 
2      John     1     123 ave 
2      John     2     456 blvd
```

Comment: but what if i added a record in table one Joe Doe and Joe Doe doesn't have any address associated with him yet. Now when i do a search for Joe Doe, then Joe Doe should come up with no address. But it returns nothing.

i want to left join because i want to show address info on name search.

Comment: when i do it separately like table1 left outer join table 2 i get the correct result. but when i do all 3 it errors out on the ON condition. this is because there's no address id on the new name. any idea how to avoid this? like check if null skip or something? i alread have defaultifempty but it doesn't help. thanks

Answer (score 0):

i ended up having to redefined my structure after the join like this

```
var query = from t1 in table1 
        join t3 in table3 on t1.id equals t3.table1id into leftt1 
        from l1 in leftt1.defaultifempty(new t3 {table1id=table1id.id, table2id=0}) 
        join t2 in table2 on l1.table2id equals t2.id 
        select.......
```

you can do the same for the other ones as well. it is working now. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
var query = from t1 in table1s 
            join t3 in table3s on t1.Id equals t3.table1Id 
                into left1
            from l1 in left1.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join t2 in table2s on (l1 == null ? -1 : l1.table2Id) equals t2.Id
                into left2
            from l2 in left2.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new { t1, l2 };
```

So you don't need a dummy `t3` instance to cross the outer join gap.